# How to add SRV records to connect Google Talk to federated networks using DynDNS?

Tags: domain-name-system, g-suite, dyndns, dns-server

I am new and paying user of DynDNS. I'd like users at my domain to have the ability to chat with people connected to the Google Talk network through federated networks (e.g. using [Meebo](http://www.meebo.com/support/article/41/)) According to [the Google FAQ](http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=34143) I need to add some SRV records but I have no idea how to do that from the DynDNS interface.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: DynDNS appears to answer this: http://www.dyndnscommunity.com/questions/732/adding-srv-records-for-google-talk-federation-to-custom-dns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the DNS server that they use you sometimes need to remove the priority value and place it in the separate priority field (like you would an MX record).

The standard format for a SRV record is

```
_service._proto.name TTL class SRV priority weight port target
```

Using the Advanced interface you'd put _xmpp-server._tcp. in the Host box, SRV as the record type and then the

```
5 0 5269 xmpp-server.l.google.com.
```

Repeat for each further entry.

If that doesn't work you can change the entry to

```
0 5269 xmpp-server.l.google.com.
```

and put the 5 in the priority table (as you would an MX record)